# how to properly link boost regex?

Tags: c++, regex, boost, mingw, static-linking

This code compiles ok:

```
#include <boost\regex.hpp>
int main() {
  boost::regex reg("[a-z]+");
}
```

But where it comes to linking there is error message:

```
d:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: final link failed: Invalid operation
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What option in commandline must I put ?
my current switches are:

```
-I "d:\mingw\include" -I "d:\boost" -Os -s -o "test.exe" "test.cpp" -std=c++11 -ftree-vectorize -static
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding `-lboost_regex` or `-lboost_regex-mt`

Comment: none of these work, I got: `d:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lboost_regex` or `ld.exe: cannot find -lboost_regex-mt`

Comment: are there any libraries somewhere under D:\boost? (*.a or *.dll) You may need to add -L path-to-libraries-directory before -l.

Comment: Well, there are none... I got boost from here: `http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/1.52.0/boost_1_52_0.7z` and there are no such files. How to get them ?

Comment: You've got sources, now you have to compile them. Here is an instruction: http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/mingw-w64/wiki/Building%20Boost (maybe there are precompiled boost binaries for mingw somewhere on the Internet -- try searching if compiling seems too hard)